# Migrate old .csproj types like WPF or XNA to Visual Studio 2017 new csproj

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, xna

I like the new .csproj format introduced in 2017 but I'm disappointed that no .NET framework project templates got any new .csproj templates (Yes, XNA doesn't have one for obvious reasons).

I've already managed to take a base .NET Standard library and turn it into a .NET Framework executable using the new format, but this doesn't seem to work for any projects that rely on the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` tag for special functionality. WPF xaml files refuse to use the designer and the *add new Window* ability isn't present anywhere (Strangely enough, UserControl *is* present).

XNA is more understandable why it doesn't work, but my first and main roadblock I'm encountering is that the old method for including XNA dlls doesn't work (Get the warning icon) and new methods are just as fruitless. I can't seem to find how to add extra reference paths to new .csproj formats like in the old format.

Anyways, is this even possible to do at the moment in Visual Studio 2017, or are these specialized project types consigned to the old .csproj format for now?

Answer (score 1):

Old project types like WPF, Winforms [don't support the new csproj](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/491#issuecomment-350208374) format via Microsoft SDK at the moment.

There are [some hacks](https://github.com/aienabled/WpfNewProjectSystemSample), [additional SDKs](https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras) which [try to solve it](https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras/blob/master/TestProjects/Windows-Desktop-C%23/WPF-Application/WPF-Application.csproj).

So currently you should stay at old format.